# Using validated method with array in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5

This is the rquest body:

```
{
    "arr": [
        {
            "a": 3,
            "b": 3
        },
        {
            "a": 3,
            "b": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

and with this validations rules:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // 'arr' => 'array',
            'arr.*.a' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

The result of `dd($request->validated());` is what I want, I don't need `b` to be included

```
"arr" => array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "a" => 3
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      "a" => 3
    ]
  ]
```

But when I want to validate the array itself like this:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'arr' => 'array',
            'arr.*.a' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

`b` will be added to the output

```
"arr" => array:2 [
    0 => array:1 [
      "a" => 3,
      "b" => 3
    ]
    1 => array:1 [
      "a" => 3,
      "b" => 3
    ]
  ]
```

How can I prevent adding b to the `dd($request->validated());` while validating the array itself?

Comment: That's not how Laravel validation works. It's a validation, not a transformation.

Comment: You can't so it with pure validation. See this discussions in Laravel/ideas repository: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/84 And https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/203

Comment: @EliasSoares I'm following https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#mass-assignment so it's not a good idea?

Comment: Why you want to exclude `d.*.b` from `$request->validated()` ? validator will automatically exclude it from their validate-rule

Comment: it technically validated the `arr` field, which happens to be the entire array, so you get the entire array ... it is actually setting `arr.1.a` and `arr.2.a` as well, but you already have the array

Comment: @NikleshRaut I want to use it like this `$category->article()->create($request->validated());` not for validation. Sorry my mistake it was `arr.*.b`

Comment: @lagbox yeah and my question is how to exclude the unwanted elements inside the array

Comment: @Ali : you need to make another array from requested data. you can use `->pluck()` or simply `foreach` method

Comment: @NikleshRaut But I cannot follow the https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#mass-assignment anymore!

Comment: Your question is now turn from 'validation' to 'mass assignment', I think you should delete this and create another with proper requirement . and if you are following any tutorial then follow completely.